# Change link when certain buttons are active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button on my page that is linked to another website, but I also have multiple buttons on that same page. I would like for when one button is active, and the others are not, that the link changes. So each link is unique to that button, but only work when it is active and the other is not. How could I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by when its active and what must it change to?

Comment: I have sizes buttons for a product, and I have code that will make one of the buttons class active when it is clicked, and the others will not be active. I then have a purchase button which right now only is linked to one page, but I want, for example, when the size 8 is clicked the purchase button link changes, and then when the size 10, for example, button is clicked and active, the purchase button link is different then that of the size 8. Let me know if that helped

Comment: I've added your answer, please try it on jsfiddle or something. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll have to ensure the following:

1. When the size button is clicked, it should have an active background color. Any other button that was previously clicked, will no longer be active.
2. Each size button will change the link location when you click the Purchase button.

**Idea**:

The idea will be to by default add a `.wrap` and you want to wrap the `<a href>` tag around the `button`.

You also want to add a class, in my example `.active`. This class will also be added.

However, when you click a different button, all these must be removed from the previous button.

So, by default, before adding a class AND before wrapping the purchase button with a link, you want to remove it (even if it doesn't exists, by default remove first then add).

**Try this**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#size-8" ).click(function() {
     $("purchase").unwrap();
     $("#purchase").wrap( "<a href='https://www.w3schools.com' target='_blank'></a>");
     $("button").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  
  $( "#size-9" ).click(function() {
     $("purchase").unwrap();
     $("#purchase").wrap( "<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'></a>");
     $("button").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="size-8">Size 8</button>
<button id="size-9">Size 9</button>

<br>

<button id="purchase">Purchase</button>
```

To see the results, go to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6eLjh5g8/) and click run.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is there a way that you can add buttons above the sizes, for example 1 and 2. So that when button 1 is active and size 9 is active it goes to google9.com for example, but if button 1 is active and size 8 is active is goes to google8.com for example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var btns = $(".btn");
btns.on("click", function(e){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
});
$(".go").on("click", function(e){
  //window.open('http://' + $(".active").attr("data-id")); <-- you can uncomment this.
  console.log('http://' + $(".active").attr("data-id"));
})
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  class="btn" data-id="www.google.com">google</button>
<button  class="btn" data-id="www.facebook.com">facebook</button>
<button  class="btn" data-id="www.amazon.com">amazon</button>

<button class="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ".active" class name to the toggled button and add a "data-link" attribute to your button

```js
var link = "";
window.onload = function() {
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("option");

  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

    btns[i].onclick = function() {
      disableAll( btns );
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      link = this.getAttribute("data-link");
    }
  }
}

function disableAll( btns ) 
{
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
  {
    if (btns[i].classList.contains("active") )
    {
        btns[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

function go()
{
  if( link != "" )
    window.location = link;
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="option" data-link="https://google.com">Google</button>

<button class="option" data-link="https://apple.com">Apple</button>


<button onclick="go();">Go</button>
```

Obviously, this code snippet's `window.location` will not work since google and apple do not allow embeds.